# transform a BitmapImage and Save it

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'm doing an image viewer (in a screen saver so images change randomly) in WPF and i would like to rotate a picture and save it at the same time (so it's rotated and i dont need to bother anymore).
I'm using Doubleanimation to fade one picture to the next.

Here is the function to rotate the image :

```
   private void RotateImage(string path, float rotationAngle)
    {
        BitmapImage CurrentImage = new BitmapImage();
        TransformedBitmap newTransformedImage = new TransformedBitmap();
        Image img = new Image();

        CurrentImage.BeginInit();
        CurrentImage.UriSource = new Uri(path);
        CurrentImage.EndInit();

        newTransformedImage.BeginInit();
        newTransformedImage.Source = CurrentImage;
        RotateTransform transform = new RotateTransform(90);
        newTransformedImage.Transform = transform;
        newTransformedImage.EndInit();
        img.Source = newTransformedImage;

        Savetojpg(img, path);
    }
```

and here is the funtion to save:

```
   private void Savetojpg(Image image, string filePath)
    {
        var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
   
        RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)image.ActualWidth, (int)image.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        Size visualSize = new Size(image.ActualWidth, image.ActualHeight);
        image.Measure(visualSize);
        image.Arrange(new Rect(visualSize));
        bitmap.Render(image);
        BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
        encoder.QualityLevel = 100;
        encoder.Frames.Add(frame);

        using (var stream = File.Create(filePath))
        {
            encoder.Save(stream);
        }
    }
```

When i run this, i have a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException at the first line of the Savetojpg function as it seems the image i'm sending to that function is empty.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: I think there's a fundemental mistake you're making here in thinking you should be doing this with WPF. WPF is not a replacement for GDI, it's a seperate 3D accelerated layer that coexists alongside GDI for the specific purpose of display. Load, transform and save your image using GDI (i.e. the Graphics/Bitmap classes and RotateTransform method), then pass the result of that to your WPF layer for conversion to BitmapSource for rendering.

Comment: Thank you Mark, so i'd need to create a specific class for image management ?

Comment: There's no specific need for a seperate class, but in general yes, you'd typically put that code in a separate helper class for good seperation-of-concerns. Also, ignore what I said about Graphics/RenderTransform, I completely forgot there's now an Image.RotateFlip function that can do this (and of course the Bitmap(Bitmap) ctor if you need to make a copy of the bitmap first). – Mark Feldman 14 mins ago

Comment: this is what i did Mark, and yes no more trouble with image management doing that. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: JPEG rotation may be done by EXIF Orientation, as e.g. digital cameras do, see [here](https://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html). An image viewer should support this on reading an image, and probably also be able to modify the Orientation value. WPF does not do that out of the box, but it can be implement with BitmapFrame.Metadata. No need for GDI.